# Usage of “very cardiac”

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

I’m trying to describe the disease is related mostly to the heart, and I found the word “cardiac” meaning “relating to the heart.” Can I describe it as “the disease is very cardiac”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English, some adjectives are [gradable](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/adjectives-gradable-and-non-gradable)- something can be more or less X- and others are not. As an example, **good** is considered to be gradable, but **perfect** is not. Pre-1900, it was relatively common to use **very** with ungradable adjectives, but in modern English it sounds wrong.

There is no universal reference for which adjectives are gradable and which aren't, but in my opinion cardiac would not be gradable, so you should not use **very** with it.

When you say that a disease is related mostly to the heart, do you mean that most of the symptoms of the disease concern the heart, or that the disease is more likely to occur in people that have other heart problems... or something else? I think that it would be better to explain in full what you really mean, rather than trying to look for a short way of saying something that is already unclear.

That said, this [NGram graph](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22heart%20related%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2017,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en) shows that the expression "heart related" does occur in health related publications.

Comment: I’m sad, there is even no implicit reference in dictionaries like the OED which adjectives are non-gradable.

Comment: *Primarily* or *predominantly* might fit the case.